# How to change the x axis limit in a Contour plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want my plot to show 7000 also in the x axis because there are values that are more than 6000 in my data.

[image]
I have tried using `set_xlim(right = 7000)` but an error pops up saying

> 'QuadContourSet' object has no attribute 'set_xlim'

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def contour_plot(filename):

# Reading the porosity data from the dat file

    data = (np.loadtxt("filename"))
    # Making two empty lists to account for the size of each grid block

    x1=[]
    for i in range(0,54):
        x1.append(i*130.75)

    x2=[]
    for j in range(0,44):
        x2.append(j*130.75)
    # Using pyplot.contourf() to make contours using the porosity values and 
    pyplot.colorbar() to show the chart for correlation

    plt.contourf(x1, x2, data[::-1])
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title("Porosity")
    #plt.savefig('Porosity.png',bbox_inches='tight')
    plot.set_xlim(right = 7000)

contour_plot("Nechelik.dat")
```

Comment: `ax.set_xlim(right = 7000)` is in principle right. But you need to choose the correct object for `ax`. You do not show this in the code, so one cannot say where it fails. See [mcve].

Comment: I have done the edit, can you please check now?

Comment: Did you try plt.xlim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a subplot you need to use `ax.set_xlim()` or you can use `plt.xlim()` for a single plot with the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html).

For a subplot:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.contourf(x1, x2, data[::-1])
ax.set_xlim(right=7000)
```

Or in your case:

```
plt.contourf(x1, x2, data[::-1])
plt.xlim(right=7000)
```